# Validate Domain in email via HTML validations ( RegEx)

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I have a login form. Here I want HTML to validate email address which is entered in the username input. But here is the part which I am unable to do, I want it to validate that the email should be of a specific domain only. E.g. - only email's with @mysite.ae should be allowed. I am aware that it can be done using RegEx but not sure how to implement it in my case

```html
<div class="signInInputLabel" id="userNameLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  Username:
</div>
<div>
  <input id="username" name="username" class="signInInputText" type="email" required>
</div>
<div class="signInInputLabel" id="passwordLabel" aria-hidden="true">Password:</div>


<div>
  <input id="password" onfocus="g_fFcs=0" name="password" value="" type="password" class="signInInputText" aria-labelledby="passwordLabel" required />
</div>
<div class="signInEnter">
  <div class="signinbutton" role="button" tabIndex="0">
    <button type="submit" style="background-color:Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:25px;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;" class="signinTxt">
      <img class="imgLnk" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      alt="" onsubmit="submit();">

      <span class="signinTxt">sign in</span>
  </div>
  </button>
  <input name="isUtf8" value="1" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to your existing validations?

Comment: @RohitAgre : I am using simple html validations as mentioned in the code above. In the username part I am using <input type="email" & required >.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just add the RegEx pattern to your input?

```
<input id="username" ... pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@mysite.ae$">
```

Comment: I like your approach. Although browser support is limited http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Answer (score 1):

here's your regex `[a-zA-Z0-9._+\-%]+@mysite.ae$`

You can use it like this.

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="signInInputText" type="email" required onChange="alert(validateMe(this))">

function validateMe(t) {
  return (/[a-zA-Z0-9._+\-%]+@mysite.ae$/.test(t.value)) ? "True. change this to what you want" : "False. Change this to what you want";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! it is working. Only 1 issue. When I enter any value and then press tab it shows an error written as false if the value is incorrect. How do I change the text false and write something else there ?

Comment: Thanks ! One more thing can you help me with ? You can see I have disable enter key in order to stop form being submitted without validation. How do I enable it but make sure both the input values are filled before submission using the enter key ?

Comment: I did not understand? can you show me your code to disable enter key that you have written?

Comment: :Take look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553793/form-validation-and-submit-on-submit-text-image-with-validation-on-enter-butto/36556127#36556127